# Adding one Character in each possible Position in a String in Java

Tags: java

I want to insert every character into each index of a string in order to check if it is a word in the dictionary. For example,
Word -> complte
I want my code to insert
(a-z)complte
c(a-z)omplte
co(a-z)mplte
And then check if It is in the dictionary. Currently my code only adds each character at the front of the string for some reason.

```
Scanner myDocReader = new Scanner(myDoc);
            while(myDocReader.hasNext()) {;;
                String word = myDocReader.next();
                word = word.toLowerCase();
                word = word.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}","");//Removes all punctuation
                
                //Case 1: Add One Character in Each Possible Position
                StringBuilder newWord = new StringBuilder(word);
                StringBuilder reset = new StringBuilder(word);
                
                
                if(!correctWords.contains(word)) {
                    //Add One Character in each possible Position
                    for(int i=0; i<word.length(); i++) {
                        for(char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++) {
                            newWord = newWord.insert(i, ch);
                            String newWord1 = newWord.toString();
                            System.out.println(newWord1);
                            if(correctWords.contains(newWord1)) {
                                System.out.println("Suggestion: " + word + "->" + newWord1);
                                newWord = reset;
                                continue;
                            }
                            newWord = reset;
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
```

Example output of current Code
a(string)
b(string)
cb(string)
dcb(string)
What I want:
a(string)
b(string)
c(string)
d(string)
.....

Comment: This is a horribly inefficient way to handle auto correct functionality.  You'd be better off storing your words into an index and using SOUNDEX (or similar algorithms) to search the index.

Comment: Did I ask about efficiency? Its for an assignment where I need to check each and every combination, if you didn't know how to help me u could have just said that.

Comment: @drewzera Mind your attitude. You are asking expert programmers for their assistance, free of cost. Show some respect. This is a collegial space, not a gamer chat room. A better response would be to thank Ryan for the feedback, and then edit your Question to note  that your task is an exercise without concern for efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String word = "complte";
    Set<String> dictionary = new HashSet<>();
    dictionary.add("complete");
    List<String> suggestions = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for (int i = 1; i < word.length(); i++) {
        for (byte j = 'a'; j <= 'z'; j++) {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append(word.substring(0, i));
            builder.append((char) j);
            builder.append(word.substring(i, word.length()));                   
            if (dictionary.contains(builder.toString())) {
                suggestions.add(builder.toString());
            }
        }           
    }
    
    if (!suggestions.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Suggestions: ");
        for (String suggestion : suggestions) {
            System.out.println(suggestion);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you write `newWord = reset` then `newWord` and `reset` will refer to the same object and thus modifying `newWord` will modify `reset` also. This is my implementation :

```
        if(!correctWords.contains(word)) {
            //Add One Character in each possible Position
            for(int i=0; i<word.length(); i++) {
                for(char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++) {
                    newWord = newWord.insert(i, ch);
                    String newWord1 = newWord.toString();
                    System.out.println(newWord1);
                    if(correctWords.contains(newWord1)) {
                        System.out.println("Suggestion: " + word + "->" + newWord1);
                        newWord.replace(i,i+1,"");
//                        newWord = reset;
                        continue;
                    }
                    newWord.replace(i,i+1,"");
//                    newWord = reset;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
```